# flutter container with fade out left effect

Tags: flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-animation

I am new at flutter. The user clicks on a button then the container will move left and hide anyone pls help me how to achieve this

```
              TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                 
                  hide = !hide;
                });
              },
              child: Text("Hide"))

              hide ? Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.black,
              ):Container(

              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for an [`AnimatedPositioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html) widget for the movements as well as [`Opacity`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widget for the opacity.

You can [preview the solution with this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/9fe5e534a3dd4adadaeaa45f6a7090ac?null_safety=true) and play around with it.

Here's the result:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              hide = !hide;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            "Hide",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Stack(children: [
            AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              right: hide ? 150 : 0,
              child: AnimatedOpacity(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                opacity: hide ? 0 : 1,
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ]),
    );
```